# store does not refreshed in reconfigure extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using Reconfigure function to change the columns and data of the panel form.

grid.reconfigure(globalStore, tmpColumns);

The grid has pagging bar

The code is working,and the data is changed. But paging and total does show old data.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it

```
 var pagingBar = grid.getDockedItems()[1];
 pagingBar.unbind(store);

  store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: tmpFields,
            pageSize: itemsPerPage,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: getDataWithPageURL,
                reader: Ext.create('CustomReader', { root: 'Results', totalProperty: 'Total' })
            }
        });


        store = store.load({
            params: {
                start: 0,
                limit: itemsPerPage
            }
        });


pagingBar.bind(store);
```